# Coldfusion - How to prevent the execution of ajax "GET" query on the server

Tags: angularjs, security, coldfusion

I'm developing an application in Coldfusion and AngularJS. I'm use AngularJS 1 and CF11.

A user has to be logged into the application. The user id is saved in the CF session.

In myAngularJS service I implemented Factories like that:

```
app.factory('ContactService', function($http){

    var factory={};

    factory.getContact=function(id){
        return $http.post('http://myapp/contacts.cfc?method=getContacts&subsString=' + id);
    };

    return factory;     
})
```

Here my component *contacts.cfc*

```
<cfcomponent displayname="Contacts" hint="Webservice for contacts app">

   <cffunction name="getContacts" access="remote" returnformat="JSON" output="no">
        <cfargument name="subsString" required="no" type="String" />

        <cfset ret = arrayNew(1) />
        <cftry>   

            <cfinclude template="cfc/person/qry/qry_Search.cfm" />
            <cfloop from="1" to="#qryFastSearch.recordcount#" index="i">   

                <cfset searchVO = structNew() />
                <cfset searchVO['ID']= #qryFastSearch.ID[i]# />         
                <cfset searchVO['PERSON']= #qryFastSearch.personName[i]# />
                <cfset searchVO['COMPANY']= #qryFastSearch.COMPANY[i]# />

                <cfset ret[i] = searchVO />
            </cfloop>

            <cfcatch type="any">
                <cfset returnVO = structNew() />
                <cfset returnVO.ERROR = true />
                <cfset returnVO.MESSAGE = cfcatch.Message />
                <cfset ret[1] = returnVO />
            </cfcatch>
        </cftry> 

        <cfreturn SerializeJSON(ret)>       
    </cffunction>

</cfcomponent>
```

When the system execute the controller, the factory is executed and the results appear. We can see in the console of the browser the url executed.

For example: http://myapp/contacts.cfc?method=getContacts&subsString=test

I would like to avoid a person to execute a query (thanks to this kind of url) if she is not connected into the application.

Is it equally possible to hide the url in the browser ?

What is the best way in order to do that ?

Many thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Add an argument to the function to receive something indicating the person is logged in.  Next, check the received value to ensure it's valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add to Dan's comment:

1. Ensure the user is logged in.
2. Check the value of `CGI.REQUEST_METHOD`. If it's not `POST`, then reject the request.
3. If you have roles & privileges, verify the user should access that URL.
4. Validate search parameters as best you can.

Since you're using `$http.post()`, you shouldn't be passing the `subString` in the query string. It should be part of the posted data to avoid browser caching and entries in the server logs that possibly shouldn't be there.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Just a question: is it better a POST or a GET method?

Comment: That all depends, if you're changing data with the request, a POST or PUT is better. If you're just requesting data, then a GET is fine.

Answer (score 0):

You state, "The user id is saved in the CF session".  Pass it as an argument to your function.

```
<cffunction name="getContacts" access="remote" returnformat="JSON" output="no">
<cfargument name="subsString" required="no" type="String" />
<cfargument name="userId" required="yes" type="String" />
```

Then check for it.

```
 <cfif StructKeyExists(session, "userId")
 and session.userId is arguments.userId>
 rest of function
 <cfelse>
 whatever you want goes here.
```